# regular expression for a block of code beginning with an all caps word?

Tags: python, regex, text, text-files

I have one file that presents the following estructure:

```
.
.
LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_1, First_1    Cell Phone: 999-999-999
Address
Needham MA 02135
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:

Salutation:


LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_2, First_2    Cell Phone: 999-999-999
Address 
Needham MA 02135
E-mail :    email@gmail.com
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    F   Env.No.:

Salutation:
.
.
```

The information between lines change a lot, what I want is to obtain a regular expression that takes the block of code that between two cap words larger than 3 letters including the first cap word. In this case i would like to include LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_1 and everything before LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_2, what regular expression can handle that?

Comment: Are you expecting non-ASCII letters in your names? If you do, this task becomes complicated.

Comment: No I don't expect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ASCII letters only, and that your data is in a variable called `text`, you should be able to use something like the following:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'^[A-Z]{3}.*?(?=^[A-Z]{3}|\Z)', text, re.S | re.M)
```

The `re.S` (or `re.DOTALL`) makes it so that `.` will match line breaks, the `re.M` (or `re.MULTILINE`) flag makes it so that `^` and `$` will match at the beginning and ends of lines respectively rather than just at the beginning and end of the string.  The `\Z` is an anchor to the end of the string, and `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead.

So here is a description of what this regex does:
Match starting at a line that begins with three uppercase characters (`^[A-Z]{3}`), then match any number of characters (as few as possible) including line breaks (`.*?`) until you would be able to match the beginning of a line that starts with three uppercase characters or you have reached the end of the string (`(?=^[A-Z]{3}|\Z)`).

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier with a simple regex that detects the lines of interest and then manually splitting on those idices.

Given this test string:

```
txt='''\
.
.
LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_1, First_1    Cell Phone: 999-999-999
Address
Needham MA 02135
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:

Salutation 1:

LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_2, First_2    Cell Phone: 999-999-999
Address
Needham MA 02135
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:

Salutation 2:


LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_3, First_3    Cell Phone: 999-999-999
Address 
Needham MA 02135
E-mail :    email@gmail.com
Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    F   Env.No.:

Salutation 3:
.
.'''
```

Try:

```
idx=[m.start(1) for m in re.finditer(r'^([A-Z_0-9]+,\s+)', txt, re.S | re.M)]
print [txt[i:j] for i,j in zip([0]+idx, idx+[None])[1:]]
```

Prints:

```
['LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_1, First_1    Cell Phone: 999-999-999\nAddress\nNeedham MA 02135\nStatus: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:\n\nSalutation 1:\n\n', 
 'LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_2, First_2    Cell Phone: 999-999-999\nAddress\nNeedham MA 02135\nStatus: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:\n\nSalutation 2:\n\n\n', 
 'LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_3, First_3    Cell Phone: 999-999-999\nAddress \nNeedham MA 02135\nE-mail :    email@gmail.com\nStatus: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    F   Env.No.:\n\nSalutation 3:\n.\n.']
```

*Note:* I only use `r'^([A-Z_0-9]+,\s+)'` to match the pattern in your example; if you have 'all caps' that match a different pattern, use that obviously.

---

And for a Python only solution (no regex) you can do:

```
lines=txt.splitlines()

line_idx=[i for i, line in enumerate(lines) 
                     if line.partition(',')[0].isupper()]

print [lines[i:j] for i,j in zip([0]+line_idx, line_idx+[None])][1:]
```

Prints:

```
[['LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_1, First_1    Cell Phone: 999-999-999', 'Address', 'Needham MA 02135', 'Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:', '', 'Salutation 1:', ''], 
 ['LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_2, First_2    Cell Phone: 999-999-999', 'Address', 'Needham MA 02135', 'Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    M   Env.No.:', '', 'Salutation 2:', '', ''], 
 ['LAST_NAME_IN_CAPS_3, First_3    Cell Phone: 999-999-999', 'Address ', 'Needham MA 02135', 'E-mail :    email@gmail.com', 'Status: Attender    Marital:    Married Adult:  Y   M/F:    F   Env.No.:', '', 'Salutation 3:', '.', '.']]
```

The advantage of the non-regex version is it it easier to support international characters:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

txt='''\
ABÇ, 
ABC, 
abc, 
ĖFG, '''

print [i for i, line in enumerate(txt.splitlines()) 
               if line.partition(',')[0].isupper()]
# [0, 1, 3]
```